# Superquadratic boundedness from $L^2$ convergence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Assume $f_n,f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $f_n\to f$ strongly in $L^2$. It seems there is a common fact that there exists a superquadratic maps $\beta\in C([0,\infty);[0,\infty))$ such that $\beta(0)=0$, $\beta(t)t^{-2}\to+\infty$ as $t\to+\infty$, $\beta(t)t^{-1}\to+\infty$ as $t\to0^+$, and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\beta(f_n)\,dx\le C<\infty$ where $C$ is independent of $n$. I have seen in many papers but I can't find it in the textbooks.

Comment: Your statement can't possibly be correct. For any $\epsilon \in (0,3/2)$ the function $f(x) = (1 + x^2)^{-3/2 - \epsilon}$ is in $L^2(R^3)$. But for any $\beta$ with $\lim_{t\to 0^+} \beta(t)/t = +\infty$, the integral $\int_{R^3} \beta(f) ~dx$ cannot converge. Did you make a typo in copying down your conditions on $\beta$?

Comment: It would also help certainly if you give a reference to at least one paper that uses this "common fact".

Comment: @WillieWong: Your point is well taken, but your example doesn't quite work, you're off by a factor of $2$ in the exponent. You want something like $f\simeq |x|^{-3/2-\epsilon}$ for large $x$.

Comment: A plausible version of these conditions would be to look for a $\beta$ with $\beta(t)/t^2\to\infty$ for both $t\to 0+$ and $t\to\infty$. (It seems clear that this works for a single function, and then it might also work for a convergent sequence.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling: indeed you are right! I started typing $\langle x \rangle$ then realized that the Japanese bracket may be unfamiliar, and forgot the extra factor of 1/2. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianRemling: do you have a proof/reference handy for the case of a single function? It also seems clear to me that it should work for single functions, but I don't have a good proof for it.

Comment: @Willie Wong: Sorry, maybe I didn't make myself clear. The reference is e.g., DiPerna-Lions'paper in 1989, Global weak solutions of Vlasov-Maxwell systems, p737, the first equation, and p753, (62).

Comment: @WillieWong: I didn't really think about it, but I thought it should be an analog of the statement that if $a_n\ge 0$, $\sum a_n<\infty$, then also $\sum a_nb_n<\infty$ for certain $b_n\to\infty$. We could probably pretty much reduce it to this statement by considering $\{ x: n\le |f(x)|< n+1\}$.

Answer (score 4):

I think the concept you're looking for is the " de la Vallée Poussin criterion " which states that, for a bounded sequence $(f_n)_n$ of integrable functions, uniform integrability is equivalent to the existence of a convex superlinear function $\Phi:\mathbf{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbf{R}_+$ such that $(\Phi(|f_n|)_n$ is bounded in $L^1$. In your case your sequence converges in $L^2$ so $(f_n^2)_n$ converges in $L^1$ and is in particular uniformly integrable.

Note also that uniform integrability is something related to **large values** of the sequence, so the behavior of $\Phi$ near $0$ is irrelevant and you can basically fix it (if I am not missing some point).

Note : for a single function, this criterion tells you that any integrable function $f$ is always " a bit more " than merely integrable, in the sense that $\Phi(|f|)$ is still integrable for some superlinear function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Mateusz Kwaśnicki, the behavior of the function $\Phi$ near $0$ is relevant for the de la Vallée Poussin criterion if the underlying measure has infinite mass. In the specific case of a sequence $(f_n)_n$ of $L^2(\mathbf{R}^3)$, this can be solved either if the sequence share a uniform decay at infinity. In the DiPerna-Lions paper mentionned by the WPJ in the comments, the first occurence of the criterion does not seem to refer to the behavior near the origin of the superquadratic function $\beta$. As for the second occurence with the estimate (62), it is obtained thanks to (53) which indeed gives uniform decay at infinity but, it seems that this decay is only assumed on the velocity variable $\xi$ and I would expect to have some similar assumption in the space variable also.

Comment: The behaviour of $\Phi$ near zero becomes relevant if the underlying measure space has infinite mass, I think.

Comment: For some remarks on the de la Vallée Poussin criterion on uniform integrability, one can see [this blog post](https://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2014/03/09/de-la-vallee-poussin-on-uniform-integrability/), or [this article by Hu and Rosalsky](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spl.2010.10.015).

Comment: Oh, you're perfectly right, Mateusz, I'll correct the post. There's also this document of José Alfredo Cañizo, even though it focuses on the case of one single function : https://canizo.org/tex/vallee-poussin.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Let me give a proof in $L^1$ and construct $\beta$ only for large values of $t$. Assuming first that $f=0$ we may suppose that $f_n \geq 0$. Let $E_{k,n}=\{2^k \le f_n<2^{k+1} \}$ for $k \in Z$ so that $\sum_k 2^k|E_{k,n}| \le \int_{R^N} f_n \le \sum_k 2^{k+1}|E_{k,n}|$. Next find an increasing  sequence of integers $n_j$ such that $\sum_{|k| \geq n_j} 2^k |E_{k,n}| \leq 2^{-j}$ for every $n$. This can be done since the series tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ (for a fixed $j$ first select $\nu$ in a such a way that all series are less than $2^{-j}$ for $n >\nu$ and then fix $n_j$ for the first $\nu$ terms). Now we can define $\beta(t)=jt$ for $t \in ]2^{n_j}, 2^{n_{j+1}}]$ and $\beta(t)=t$ for $t \leq 2^{n_1}$. Then
$$\int_{R^N}\beta(f_n) \leq \int_{\{f_n \le 2^{n_1}\}}f_n+\sum_{k \geq n_1} \beta (2^{k+1} )|E_{k,n}| \le c+\sum_j j\sum_{k=n_j}^{n_{j+1}-1}2^{k+1}|E_{k,n}| \le c+2\sum_j j 2^{-j} =C.
$$
When $f \neq 0$ we apply the same construction to $|f_n-f|$ and to $|f|$ to find $\beta_1$ in such a way that $\int_{R^N}(\beta_1(|f_n-f|)+\beta_1(|f|) \le C)$. The above construction gives $\beta_1$ increasing and convex. If $\beta(t)=\beta_1(t/2)$, then $\beta(|f_n|)\le \frac12 \beta_1 (|f_n-f|)+\frac12 \beta_1(|f|)$ and the bound follows by integration. The construction neat $t=0$ can be done similarly.